# Range slider - avoid moving forward when reaching a value specified in another element

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

lets say i have a range slider going from value 1 to 100
by default i would be able to slide it going from 1 to 100.

I would like the slider to block, when reaching a value specified in another element.
I've been trying it like this (where 20 would be the value in the element, just easier for the example), but that isn't perfect. the Thumb does indeed stop, but i think internally if you keep sliding, it will remember that value, even if you don't see it.

EDIT:
would a for loop be something good here?

```
for(i=slider.value;i<20;i++)
...
```

```
if (slider.value >=20)
slider.value=20
```

Anyone better at this who can help?

Comment: your approach is good in my opinion and you don't need to check the value like  (slider.value >=20)  because you want to set it to 20 right, so just check if it is greater than 20( slider.value > 20)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap everything in a `<form>` if you haven't already then assuming your limit is set by another `<input>`, assign an event handler to the `<form>` so it will trigger whenever there's an "input" event. Have the event handler change the `[max]` attribute value of the `range` input to the `[value]` of the limit `<input>`.

```js
const limit = e => {
  const io = e.currentTarget.elements;
  let max = io.limit.value;
  io.range.max = max;
  io.view.value = io.range.value;
};

const ui = document.forms.ui;
ui.oninput = limit;
```

```css
input {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5ch;
  text-align: right;
}

#range {
  width: 20ch
}
```

```html
<form id='ui'>
  <input id='limit' type='number' max='100' value='100'>
  <output id='view'>0</output><br>
  <input id='range' type='range' min='0' max='100' value='0'>
</form>
```

Comment: Oh i like this - changing the max might actually be the big thing. thanks!   Will definately play around with this.  Thumbed up, but need more rep to go through ;)

Comment: what if the value is determined in a non input element, that is not in the same form?  I have 1 slider that has no limitations, the value of that slider gets output to a span element.  it is the value in that span i would like as the limitation for the other slider(s)
Im not that familiar with that way of coding, maybe its more modern :) i'm sure i can learn it though!

Comment: An output element is far better than a span. For an output you can use `.value` and it's a form control and if it's out of the form you can associate it with that form with `form=(id of form)` on the output. With span you need to use `.textContent` or `.innerText` and special form interfaces and APIs will not apply.

Comment: last question, then i think i'll be set.  if its out of the form where you set const io =  would that then be e.getelementbyid("formid").elements ?

Comment: BTW that way of coding is actually old, but it is terse and very efficient when dealing with [forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)

Comment: Add `form="(id of form)"` to the output tag (ex. `<output form="ui"></output>` It works for form controls only (ex. input, select, textarea, output, etc). `e.currentTarget` is the element that is bound to the event handler (ex. `ui.oninput = eventhandler` `ui` would be `e.currentTarget`)

Comment: Is there any particular reason why your form isn't over everything?

Comment: its like this:
there is Slider A.  Slider A has no limits, its just a simple slider 1-100 (for example).
lets say slider A is at 37 at the moment.
that 37 should be the limit for Slider B (and other sliders potentially)

Comment: I see...but all sliders can be under one `form` and you can control which sliders react and those that don't or even act differently than others. In the example all form controls are in one `form`  -- if you added more sliders and give them identical `[name]`s , you can use [HTMLFormControlsCollection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) to control all of them.

Comment: If you need help, start another question.